# Ternary operator: one parameter and different methods

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

I wrote some code using simple ternary operator:

```
<%= (current_user.is_company?) 
    ? company_path(current_user.character)
    : individual_path(current_user.character) %>
```

Can I write this expression more simple and laconic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no much to simplify, but here is what I can do:

```
send((current_user.is_company? ? :company_path : :individual_path),
     current_user.character)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't simplify it, but what you can do is put the code in your controller, and just render the variable on the view:

```
@real_path = current_user.is_company? ? 
  company_path(current_user.character) : 
  individual_path(current_user.character)

<%= @real_path %>
```

I believe it is less agressive to the view.

Comment: Why to add one more instance variable just to render the url?

Comment: I agree to the idea to put the ternary operator outside the view, but I would put it in a view helper rather then the controller...